# Angular 1 not parsing html loaded by click-action

Tags: jquery, angular1.6

I have strange trouble with angular 1.6. I has index.html with next code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/angular/node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
    {{1+2}}

<div id="for-load"></div>

<script>
    $("#for-load").load('/for-load.html')
</script></body>
</html>
```

and for-load.html with code "{{3+4}}". 
When i open index.html in browser, i see numbers: 3 and 7, like i wait.

But if i replace script-tag on

```
<button onclick="test()">load</button>
<script>
    function test() {
        $("#for-load").load('/for-load.html')
    }
</script>
```

and has next code (full)

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/angular/node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
    {{1+2}}

<div id="for-load"></div>

<button onclick="test()">load</button>
<script>
    function test() {
        $("#for-load").load('/for-load.html')
    }
</script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Angular stop parsing loaded html content! It's display "{{3+7}}".
I mean, if i call html-loading in document-render time - it`s good. If i call html-loading after that by button click - it's bad. Why it so?

Comment: please re-write the question, <script> tag is needed by browser in order to understand as it is script else it will parse like HTML tag only, non compatible element will be displayed as such.

Comment: Thanks, rewrited with full end code example.